# Error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 while iterating over the loop

Tags: kotlin

Response that i get

```
[{date_time: 2019-02-07 10:09:01, vital_code : S1, vital_value :25, created_at : 2019-02-07 04:39:09, id = 1}, {date_time: null, vital_code : S2, vital_value :150, created_at : null, id = null}]
```

The error is pointing out to line

```
 Process: com.example.healthpassport, PID: 21563
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.example.healthpassport.activity.HealthMetrics$onCreate$1$override.onResponse(HealthMetrics.kt:31)
    at com.example.healthpassport.activity.HealthMetrics$onCreate$1$override.access$dispatch(HealthMetrics.kt)
    at com.example.healthpassport.activity.HealthMetrics$onCreate$1.onResponse(HealthMetrics.kt)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

This is how i call and iterate over the response

```
 val call=RetrofitClient.instance.api.getVitals("Bearer "+token)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<VitalsResponse>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<VitalsResponse>>?, response: Response<List<VitalsResponse>>?) {

                Log.e("Response", response!!.body().toString())

                for (i in 0..response.body().size) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.e("Response", response!!.body()[i].getVital_value())
                        Log.e("Response", response!!.body()[i].getVital_code())
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.e("Response", "No Response")
                    }
                }
            }


        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<VitalsResponse>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("VitalResponse", t!!.message)
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    })
```

Can someone please tell me what could be the reason i'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists in Kotlin are zero-indexed, so for a list of size `N`, the first element is at index `0`, while the last one is at index `N-1`.

In your loop here...

```
for (i in 0..response.body().size)
```

You're using an inclusive range with the `x..y` syntax, so `i` will run from `0` all the way to the size of the list, which isn't a valid index.

A possible fix is to use the [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html) function to create a range that doesn't include its upper bound:

```
for (i in 0 until response.body().size)
```

Or you can also use [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html) to get a range of the valid indexes for a list:

```
for (i in response.body().indices)
```

For even more about ranges, see the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html).